# What does b != a & 1 do?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a += b != a & 1
```

I came across this statement in a code, but I'm not sure what the final part (`!= a & 1`) of the code does.  What does that do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to consult the language specification to realize what the order of operations are here. With parentheses put out this will be:

```
a += (b != (a & 1))
```

The `a & 1` is bitwise and (making it `1` if `a` is odd and `0` otherwise), then the result of that is compared to `b` and the result of that which is boolean will be added to `a`. Now of course for the latest to be meaningful `a` need to be of a type that can support that (integer types does that for example, by taking `True` as having value of `1` and `False` having value of `0`).

To sum it up, if `b==0` it will increase `a` if `a` is even and if `b==1` it will increase `a` if `a` is odd. Otherwise if `b` is neither `0` nor `1` it will increase `a`.

I noticed that some of the comments didn't notice the precedence order, and even in python they may sometimes be confusing (especially if you've already been confused by those from C). As a rule of thumb I'd recommend that you explicitely place parentheses around sub expressions if you're in the tiniest bit of doubt - or even break it down in separate statemenst. Normally the compiler will make the best of it anyway.

Comment: What effect does the code have? Try it with some values, e.g. `a < b`

Comment: @PeterWood I've updated the answer, the relation between `a` and `b` is irrelevant. The relevant condition is whether `a` is even or odd and if `b` is `0` or `1`  (or something else).

Comment: If b does not compare equal to either 0 or 1, a will always be incremented.

Comment: @YannVernier Thanks for spotting that, I've changed that now.